# Is $(\sum_{i=1}^m (x _ {i})^{n})^{n+1} \le (\sum_{i=1}^m (x_{i})^{n+1})^{n}$ true for sufficiently large $n$

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces

I'm working on this [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3315857/the-cdot-p-norm-will-become-the-maximum-norm-when-p-to-infty) about the relationship between $\ell_{p}$ norm and $\ell_{\infty}$. This leads me to evaluate the below inequality.

$$\left( \sum_{i=1}^m \left( x _ { i } \right) ^ { n } \right) ^ { n + 1 } \le \left( \sum_{i=1}^m \left( x _ { i } \right) ^ { n + 1 } \right) ^ { n }, \quad (x_1, \ldots,x_m) \in {(\mathbb R^+)}^m$$

I would like to ask whether there exists $N \in \mathbb N$ such that this inequality holds for all $n \ge N$.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just plug in $x_i=1$ you will get $m^{n+1}\leq m^n$ which is not true

Comment: What is the reason for downvoting my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your inequality is equivalent to 
$$\|x\|_{\ell_p^{n}}\leq \|x\|_{\ell_p^{n+1}}$$ which is not true. Actually, the reverse inequality is valid.

Answer (score 3):

Take $x_i=1$ for all $i$ to see that it is false for any $m>1$ however large you take $N$ to be.

Comment: I don't downvote your answer. I actually just upvoted it. I don't understand why my question is downvoted too.

Comment: I don't know, looks like a fine answer to me.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Probably because this was commented already before your answer.