# Let $E$ be a Hilbert space and $p \in (1, \infty)$. Then $L_p(X, \mu, E)$ is reflexive

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, reflexive-space

I'm reading Brezis's *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations*, and trying to generalize *Theorem 4.10* from $\mathbb R$ to to a Hilbert space $E$. Could you have a check on my attempt?

> **Theorem:** Let $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space. Let $(E, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_H)$ be a Hilbert space (over the field $\mathbb R$) and $|\cdot|$ its induced norm. Then $L_p := L_p(X, \mu, E)$ is reflexive for all $p \in (1, \infty)$.

---

**My attempt:** The proof consists of three steps.

> a. $$\left \| \frac{f+g}{2} \right \|^p_p + \left \| \frac{f-g}{2} \right \|^p_p \le \frac{\|f\|_p^p + \|g\|_p^p}{2} \quad \forall f,g \in L_p, \forall p \in [2, \infty).$$

Clearly, it suffices to prove that
$$\left | \frac{a+b}{2} \right |^p + \left | \frac{a-b}{2} \right |^p \le \frac{|a|^p + |b|^p}{2} \quad \forall a,b \in E.$$

Notice that we have below [inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3317248/1019043)
$$
\bigg ( \sum_{i=1}^m (x_{i})^{p} \bigg)^{q} \ge \bigg( \sum_{i=1}^m (x_{i})^{q} \bigg)^{p}, \quad \forall (x_1, \ldots,x_m \ge 0), \forall (q\ge p \ge 0).
$$

Hence
$$
\left | \frac{a+b}{2} \right |^p + \left | \frac{a-b}{2} \right |^p \le \left [ \left | \frac{a+b}{2} \right |^2 + \left | \frac{a-b}{2} \right |^2 \right ]^{p/2} = \left [ \frac{|a|^2+|b|^2}{2} \right ]^{p/2} \le  \frac{|a|^p + |b|^p}{2}.
$$

The last inequality is due to the convexity of the map $\varphi:\mathbb R_{\ge 0} \to \mathbb R_{\ge 0}, x \mapsto x^{p/2}$.

> b. $L_p$ is uniformly convex and [thus](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4382810/1019043) reflexive for all $p \in (2, \infty)$.

Fix $f,g\in L_p$ such that $\|f\|_p, \|g\|_p \le 1$ and $\|f-g\|_p \ge \varepsilon >0$. By (a), we get
$$
\left \| \frac{f+g}{2} \right \|_p \le \left [ 1- \left ( \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \right)^p \right ]^{1/p} = 1- \delta
\quad \text{with} \quad
\delta := \left \{1-\left [ 1- \left ( \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \right)^p \right ]^{1/p} \right \} >0.
$$

> c. $L_p$ is reflexive for all $p \in (1, 2]$.

We define an operator $T: L_p \to (L_{p'})^*$ with $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p'} = 1$ by
$$
\langle Tf, g \rangle := \int_X \langle f, g\rangle_H \mathrm d \mu \quad \forall f \in L_p, g \in L_{p'}.
$$

Fix $f \in L_p$. Clearly, $Tf$ is linear. By Cauchy-Schwarz and Hölder inequalities,
$$
|\langle Tf, g \rangle | \le \int_X |f| \cdot |g| \mathrm d \mu \le \|f\|_p \|g\|_{p'} \quad \forall f \in L_p, g \in L_{p'}.
$$

Therefore, $\|T f\|_{(L_{p'})^*} \le \|f\|_{p}$. Let $g_0 := |f|^{p-2} f$. Then
$$
\int_X |g_0|^{p'} \mathrm d \mu = \int_X |f|^{(p-1)p'} \mathrm d \mu = \int_X |f|^{p} \mathrm d \mu < \infty.
$$

Then $g_0 \in L_{p'}$. Also,
$$
\langle Tf, g_0 \rangle = \int_X \langle f, |f|^{p-2} f\rangle_H \mathrm d \mu = \|f\|_p^p.
$$

Hence
$$
\frac{\langle Tf, g_0 \rangle}{\|g_0\|_{p'}} = \frac{\|f\|_p^p}{\|f\|_p^{p/p'}} = \|f\|_p.
$$

Hence $\|T f\|_{(L_{p'})^*} = \|f\|_{p}$. This implies $T$ is a linear isometry.

- Because $E$ is **complete**, $L_p$ [is complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4505799/the-space-l-p-l-p-omega-mu-e-is-complete-for-p-in-1-infty). So the image $T(L_p)$ is closed in $(L_{p'})^*$.
- Notice that $p \in (1, 2]$ implies $p' \in [2, \infty)$. By (b), $L_{p'}$ is reflexive.
- A Banach space is reflexive if and only if its dual is reflexive. Hence $(L_{p'})^*$ is reflexive.
- A closed linear subspace of a reflexive space is reflexive. Hence $T(L_p)$ and thus $L_p$ are reflexive. This completes the proof.