# Is my generalization of Theorem 4.14 in Brezis's Functional Analysis correct?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces

I'm reading Brezis's *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations*, and trying to generalize *Theorem 4.14* from $\mathbb R$ to a Hilbert space $H$. Let $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite complete measure space. Let $(H, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_H)$ be a Hilbert space (over the field $\mathbb R$) and $|\cdot|$ its induced norm.

> **Theorem:**  Let $\phi \in (L_1)^*$. There exists a unique $u \in L_\infty$ such that
> $$
> \langle \phi, f \rangle = \int \langle u, f \rangle_H \quad \forall f \in L_1.
> $$
> Moreover, $\|u\|_\infty = \|\phi\|_{(L_1)^*}$.

Could you have a check on my attempt?

---

**My attempt:** By $\sigma$-finiteness, there is an increasing (w.r.t. inclusion) sequence $(X_n) \subset \mathcal A$ such that $\mu (X_n) < \infty$ and $\bigcup_n X_n =X$.

> 1. Uniqueness.

Assume  $u, u' \in L_\infty$ such that
$$
\langle \phi, f \rangle = \int \langle u, f \rangle_H = \int \langle u', f \rangle_H \quad \forall f \in L_1.
$$

Then
$$
\int \langle u-u', f \rangle_H = 0 \quad \forall f \in L_1.
$$

We pick $f_0 =  (u-u')1_{X_n}$. Because $u-u'$ is essentially bounded on $X_n$ and $\mu (X_n) < \infty$, we get $f_0 \in L_1$. So
$$
\int \langle u-u', f_0 \rangle_H = 0 \iff \int |(u-u')1_{X_n}|^2 = 0.
$$

It follows that $u=u'$ $\mu$-a.e. on $X_n$. Hence $u=u'$ $\mu$-a.e.

> 2. Existence.

There exist a sequence $(\varepsilon_n) \subset \mathbb R_{>0}$ and a map $\theta \in L_2 (X, \mu, \mathbb R)$ such that $\theta (x) = \varepsilon_n$ for all $x \in X_n$. By Hölder inequality, $\theta f \in L_1$ for all $f \in L_2$. The map $L_2 \to \mathbb R, f \mapsto \langle \phi, \theta f\rangle$ is linear continuous. By [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4506440/let-e-be-a-hilbert-space-and-p-in-1-infty-then-l-p-l-p-wi), we have $(L_2)^* = L_2$. So there is $v \in L_2$ such that
$$
\langle \phi, \theta f\rangle = \int \langle v, f \rangle_H \quad \forall f \in L_2.
$$

Let $u := v /\theta$. Then $u$ is $\mu$-measurable. For all $g \in L_\infty$, we have

- $\frac{g1_{X_n}}{\theta} \in L_2$. This is because $\theta$ is constant on $X_n$, $g$ is essentially bounded on $X_n$, and $\mu(X_n) < \infty$.
- $g1_{X_n} \in L_1$. This is because $g$ is essentially bounded on $X_n$ and $\mu(X_n) < \infty$.

Hence for all $g \in L_\infty$ and $n \in \mathbb N$, we have
$$
\langle \phi,  g1_{X_n} \rangle = \left \langle \phi, \theta \left ( \frac{g1_{X_n}}{\theta} \right )\right \rangle =  \int \left  \langle v, \frac{g1_{X_n}}{\theta} \right  \rangle_H =  \int \left  \langle \frac{v}{\theta}, g1_{X_n} \right  \rangle_H = \int \langle u, g1_{X_n} \rangle_H.
$$

Next we prove that $\|u\|_\infty \le \|\phi\|_{(L_1)^*}$. Fix any $C> \|\phi\|_{(L_1)^*}$ and let $A := \{x \in X | C < |u(x)|\} \in \mathcal A$. Notice that $u > 0$ on $A$. Let $g_0 := 1_{A} \frac{u}{|u|} \in L_\infty$. Then

- $$
  |\langle \phi,  g_0 1_{X_n} \rangle| \le \|\phi\|_{(L_1)^*} \| g_0 1_{X_n}\|_1 = \|\phi\|_{(L_1)^*} \left \| \frac{u}{|u|} 1_{A\cap X_n} \right \|_1 =  \|\phi\|_{(L_1)^*} \mu (A \cap X_n).
  $$
- $$
  \int \langle u, g_0 1_{X_n} \rangle_H = \int \left \langle u, \frac{u}{|u|}1_{A \cap X_n} \right \rangle_H = \int |u|1_{A \cap X_n} \ge C \mu (A \cap X_n).
  $$

It follows that
$$
C \mu (A \cap X_n) \le \|\phi\|_{(L_1)^*} \mu (A \cap X_n).
$$

Hence $\mu (A \cap X_n) = 0$ and thus $\mu (A) = \lim_n \mu (A \cap X_n) = 0$. So $A$ is a $\mu$-null set. We claim that
$$
\langle \phi, h\rangle = \int \langle u, h\rangle_H \quad \forall h \in L_1.
$$

Let $T_n$ be the truncation operator, i.e., $(T_n h) (x) = h (x)$ if $|h (x)| \le n$ and $(T_n h) (x) = n h(x)/ |h(x)|$ otherwise. Then $(T_n h)1_{X_n} \to h$ in $L_1$ by [dominated convergence theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space). On the other hand, $T_n h \le n$ and thus $T_n h \in L_\infty$. As such,
$$
\langle \phi, (T_nh)1_{X_n}\rangle = \int \langle u, (T_nh)1_{X_n} \rangle_H.
$$

Notice that the map $L_1 \to \mathbb R, h \mapsto \int \langle u, h \rangle$ is linear continuous. Hence
$$
\langle \phi, h \rangle = \lim_n \langle \phi, (T_nh)1_{X_n}\rangle = \lim_n \int \langle u, (T_nh)1_{X_n} \rangle_H = \int \left \langle u, \lim_n (T_nh)1_{X_n} \right \rangle_H = \int \langle u, h \rangle_H.
$$

Finally, we have
$$
|\langle \phi, h \rangle| \le \int |u| |h| \le \|u\|_\infty \int |h| = \|u\|_\infty \|h\|_1.
$$

Hence $\|\phi\|_{(L_1)^*} \le \|u\|_\infty$. This completes the proof.