# Reference request: If $E$ is a reflexive Banach space, then $L_p(X, \mu, E)$ is reflexive and $(L_p(X, \mu, E))^* = L_q(X, \mu, E^*)$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, reflexive-space

Let $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite complete measure space, $(E, |\cdot|)$ a Banach space, and $p \in (1, \infty)$. Let $L_p(X, \mu, E)$. I read somewhere that

> If $E$ is reflexive, then $L_p(X, \mu, E)$ is reflexive and $(L_p(X, \mu, E))^* = L_q(X, \mu, E^*)$ with $1/p+1/q=1$.

I proved these claims for a particular case of Hilbert spaces [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4506324/let-e-be-a-hilbert-space-and-p-in-1-infty-then-l-px-mu-e-is-ref) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4506440/let-e-be-a-hilbert-space-and-p-in-1-infty-then-l-p-l-p-wi). My proofs depend on the inner product and thus can not be generalized to general reflexive Banach spaces.

Could you provide a reference for the proofs of these results?

Comment: See Diestel & Uhl, chapter 4. They characterize the dual spaces of $L^p(\mu, E)$. Proof works with Radon-Nikodym property.

Comment: @daw It seems to me that (in the book) $E$ is reflexive $\implies$ $E$ has RNP $\implies$ $(L_p(E))^* = L_q(E^*)$. I could not find the proof that $E$ is reflexive $\implies$ $L_p (E)$ is reflexive.

Comment: @Masacroso I only found the duality when $E \in \{\mathbb R, \mathbb C\}$ at page 206. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: You could just use the same theorem in Diestel & Uhl (sec 4.1) twice: $(L^p(E))^{**} = (L^q(E^{*}))^* = L^p(E^{**}) = L^p(E)$ since both $E$ and $E^*$ are reflexive, so have RNP. The following corollary in the book gives exactly the result you're after.

Comment: Thank you so much @OnurOktay. Could you post your comment as an answer?