# $L_p(X, \mu, E)$ where $E$ is a Banach space: reflexivity, separability, duality, and uniform convexity

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, bochner-spaces

At page 103 of Brezis's *Functional Analysis* there is

> The following table summarizes the main properties of the space $L_p(X, \mu, \mathbb R)$ when $X$ is a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$ :
> $$
> \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
> \hline & Reflexive & Separable & Dual space \\
> \hline L^p \textit{ with } 1<p<\infty & YES & YES & L^{q} \\
> \hline L^1 & NO & YES & L^{\infty} \\
> \hline L^{\infty} & NO & NO & \textit{Strictly bigger than } L^1 \\
> \hline
> \end{array}
> $$

Here $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1$. I would like to make an analogue for Banach spaces.

Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $(E, |\cdot|)$ a Banach space. Fix $p \in [1, \infty)$. Let $L_p := L_p (X, \mu, E)$ and $\|\cdot\|_{L_p}$ be its norm. Here we use the [Bochner integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space). Then

1. If $p \in (1, \infty)$ and $E$ reflexive, [then](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4513531/reference-request-if-e-is-a-reflexive-banach-space-then-l-px-mu-e-is) so is $L_p$.
2. If the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$ is countably generated and $E$ separable, [then](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4574940/generalize-theorem-4-13-in-breziss-functional-analysis) $L_p$ is separable.
3. $L_{p}(X, \mu, E)^{*}=L_{q}(X, \mu, E^{*})$ [IFF](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4505909/let-e-be-a-banach-space-p-in-1-infty-and-l-p-l-px-mu-e-i?rq=1) $X^{*}$ has the [Radon-Nikodým property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4546633/construct-conditional-expectation-on-banach-spaces-with-radon-nikod%c3%bdm-property) with respect to $\mu$.
4. If $p \in (1, \infty)$, then $L_p$ is uniformly convex [IFF](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434289/is-l-px-mu-e-uniformly-convex-for-p-in-1-infty-if-e-is-a-uniform)  $E$ is uniformly convex.

I'm happy to receive your correction and suggestion!

Comment: It is not clear from your posting how the properties of E are reflected in $L_p(\mu;E)$. Is $\Omega$ meant to be $E$?

Comment: @OliverDíaz $\Omega$ is a notation used by Brezis. I thought I wrote that "If...$E$ is reflexive, then so...".

Comment: @OliverDíaz I have re-arranged my thread so that It is less confusing.

Comment: I would just replace the omega by E. That way it is clear that you want to see what properties remain from the vector valued $L_p(E)$ when E is Euclidean space the case where $E$ is  more general Banach space satisfying some extra conditions.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Actually, in Brezis's book $L^p(\Omega) := L_p(\Omega, \mu, \mathbb R)$.

Comment: Which makes your posting more confusing. I think you want to pass from real finite dimensional valued integrals to Banach space valued integrals and want to see which properties on the Banach space may be required to have something that behaves well.

Comment: @OliverDíaz I have just edited again. Now I think there is no more confusion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140578/discussion-between-oliver-diaz-and-akira).

Comment: @OliverDíaz: please don't use the chat, it separates the discussion from the question and no one will ever look at it.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: Usually I try to avoid it, but sometimes Mods force long threads into chat. But I understand...

Comment: I know that sometimes mods do, but reality is that it separates the information from the question it came from. Already the system shortens the list of comments on display, so removing the comments when there is no issue with any particular comment seems pointless.